# Add special characters in cookies, java

Tags: java, json, servlets, cookies

I want to create cookie which contains special char. I have tried many solutions but it remains same. It means that it automatically deletes the values after special char.

`json = [{"message":"D10QAC"},{"message":"D10P;F"},{"message":"D10PAF"}]`

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("cookie", json); 
cookie.setMaxAge(10000);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

But when the cookie is stored is like `[{"message":"D10QAC"},{"message":"D10P;`

I also tried to decode this cookie by using `URLEncoder.encode(json, "UTF-8")` but it also have same problem.

Any help ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should provide us with the type of that json object, as well as what frameworks you are using. Where is this "Cookie" class coming from?

Comment: `@Johan.`  I have created cookies in spring framework. And the Cookie class is from `javax.servlet.http.Cookie`

Comment: Thanks. The Cookie class takes a String as json. You should show us the code to produce that String and/or what the actual value of the string is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say this is not generally possible, as `;` symbol is an escape separator character for the HTTP headers (look also on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19028585/1479414).

So probably best solution will be encode your json into base64 string and store it in cookie value.